# label of the rejection and acceptance zone

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am constructing the following graph but the acceptance and rejection labels do not look good and I tried anyway and nothing

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 4)), aes(x))
p1<-p1+stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 49, args =list(mean = 2, sd = 3/7),geom = "area",fill="blue2",alpha=0.5,aes(color="aceptacion"))
p1<-p1 +stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 2, sd = 3/7), xlim = c(2.905, 4),geom ="area", fill = "red", alpha = 0.5,aes(color="rechazo")) 
p1
```

[image]

How do I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
mycolor<- c("blue2","red")
myvalues <- c("aceptacion","rechazo")
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 4))
p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x))
p1 <- p1+stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 49, args =list(mean = 2, sd = 3/7),xlim = c(0, 2.905) ,geom = "area",fill="blue2",alpha=0.5) 
p1 <- p1 +stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 2, sd = 3/7), xlim = c(2.905, 4),geom ="area", fill = "red") 
p1 <- p1 + aes(color=myvalues)
p1 <- p1 + scale_color_manual(name="", values=mycolor)
p1 <- p1 +  guides(color= guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=mycolor)))
p1
```

You get the following output:

[image: output]

Comment: can with 3 names and 3 colors?

Comment: Yes, with any number of names and colors.  You need to have data accordingly.

Comment: I am trying to add the p-value 3.2 as for example and it gives me an aestetich error you know why?

Comment: As this question has been answered, please ask that as a separate question and show the program that is not working in your question. A small reprex like above would be great.